# Repeated measurement

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I need help to choose the right statistical analysis for a project.

I have subject that undergo repeated measurement

Sample size 8 (but will be larger). All measurements are conducted within 20 min for each patient.

My question is, how can I compare the flow in rest

Comment: Did all patients have the same order of settings or were the settings randomized? A good start could be a linear mixed effects model with the differences in bloodflow between stress - rest as outcomes, the settings as fixed predictor and a patient random intercept. Plot the data in any case.

Comment: Yes, all patients had the same order of settings. Will the linear mixed effects model also analyze if there is a difference in bloodflow in the different pacemaker-functions/settings at rest and stress?

Comment: No, the model I proposed would analyze the mean *differences* between rest and stress for each setting. Does it make sense to compare rest for each setting? Shouldn't rest be the same for all settings? How many patients do you have (please add this information to the question if possible)?

Comment: Ok, this could also be done with a mixed model, including a fixed effect for time (rest, stress) and an interaction between time and setting.